# Collect system and environment information

Tags: c#, c++, environment, userinfo

On application crashes, we are looking into the best way to collect user/environment and crash information so we can have it emailed to us.

Are there any libraries (open-source or commercial) which do this well?

Our application is a desktop application written in c# .Net with swigged c++ code.

Thanks,

Liron

Comment: related question, maby helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992569/how-do-i-obtain-a-crash-dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many obfuscation tools include error reporting, which includes this type of diagnostic functionality.  For example:

- [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) includes the ability to have [Automated Error Reporting](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/features/#automated-error-reporting).
- This is also included in the latest versions of [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview).

Comment: In one of our applications, we are running inside unity3d, so using an obfuscator isn't really an option, but it's good to know that those are built in.

Comment: @LKIM: I believe, with SmartAssembly, you can actually turn off the obfuscation and still use their error reporting.  However, you should be able to obfuscate even with Unity3D, though you'll be restricted to using lower (less secure) obfuscation settings...

Comment: Interesting - do you know if SmartAssembly can also give error information from our c++ code too?

Comment: @LKIM I think it's mostly capturing the managed exceptions.  If your C++ errors are wrapped into managed exceptions, then yes, it would...

Answer (score 1):

I like the functionality provided by Bugtrap, collecting crash dumps and "send to" functionality. Crash dumps + WinDbg gives you the tools needed to debug client errors with an experience very close to what you are used to when debugging in Visual Studio.

Bugtrap:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/BugTrap.aspx