# How to make my code creating dump file before crash?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg

I have some code in C# and C++ ( in one project ). 
This code have some crash and i trying t find it. 
but this crash is not reproduce any time - and i can't find it.

I want to configure the code / the windows OS to create dump file on the crash.

the limitation that i have are ...  I have limited access to the machine that this crash reproduce on - this is not developing machine .. this is testing Lab machine

So, How to do it ? 
How can i change the properties in the solution that a new dump file will created on any crash?

(the aim is to be able to analyze the dump in the windbg tool)

Comment: Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4992569/21567).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it easier to use [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900). Try the -e (create dump on unhandled exceptions), -ma (w/ full process memory), and -t (create dump on app termination) options.

Comment: Ah, but when the app crashes it's too late already. No question, I love ProcDump too, but this is not the right situation to use it, methinks.

Comment: You can use the -e option for unhandled exceptions. It will tell you what caused the crash.

Comment: Fair enough, and a good point +1 then. But this should be part of the answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 11):

You can register an unhandled exception filter and PInvoke [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).   A code sample to do that is located [here](http://brakertech.com/howto-c-generate-dump-file-on-crash/)

Answer (score 4):

You can enable saving dumps on vista in the registry:

1. Open RegEdit
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
3. Under Windows Error Reporting, create a new registry key named LocalDumps.